# Loading django based webpage with Apache and mod_wsgi, haystack takes upto 10 sec.

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, django-haystack

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/swpdoc/swpdoc/wsgi.py
<Directory /var/www/swpdoc>

     Require all granted

</Directory>
WSGIDaemonProcess swpdoc python-home=/var/www/swpdoc/venswpdoc python-    
path=/var/www/swpdoc
WSGIProcessGroup swpdoc
```

Any suggestion to improve the loading time ?

Comment: check what querys take so much time and try to minimize the problem. Use "Django-debug-toolbar" I guess you have a lot of duplicate querys and these make websites slow...

Comment: It is at the initial loading. I am not querying anything at initial loading. Later it become OK but first time it takes up to 10 mins.

Answer (score 0):

Are you preloading a lot of data from a database?

You can force pre-loading on process start rather than first request using:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/swpdoc/swpdoc/wsgi.py process-group=swpdoc application-group=%{GLOBAL}
```

in place of current `WSGIScriptAlias`.

You can drop `WSGIProcessGroup` after doing that.

Comment: I got the following error:   SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/httpd from ioctl access on the file   .. /../templates/search/search_view.html.